# Torrent library allowing downloading separate file pieces

Tags: java, c++, c, ruby, bittorrent

I am searching for the way to download concrete pieces of file (e.q. first or last 1Mb) via bittorrent programmically.
C / C++, Java or Ruby libraries would be good solutions for me. Is there any solution in opensource world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Azureus** is written in Java, and is provided on **SourceForge**

http://azureus.sourceforge.net/download.php

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the rtorrent client and library. It offers this functionality and much more.

Answer (score 3):

libtorrent-rasterbar, c++, with documentation

http://libtorrent.org